# Addthis button not initializing after datatables paging

Tags: jquery, datatables, addthis

First, I can't dynamically load new buttons because the custom URL for each of those buttons are generated server-side at run-time.

What I need to do is have a function that I can call on a click method.

Example:

Using datatables plugin. I have an addthis button on each row, but if there is more than one page, the button appears on the other pages but no hover effects, no addthis, not working, etc. It's just an image.

Before using Addthis I was just using Facebook, which easily allows you to call the parsing function like this:

FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('theIDwherebuttonscanbefound'));

I need a similar solution for Addthis.  I've been through the docs and just don't know what I'm missing here...

Can you please give me an example of a function I can use that searches for any addthis buttons within an area and re-initializes them? This is driving me nuts.

Thank you.

```
<a class="addthis_button" addthis:url="http://MyURLGeneratedatRuntime" href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=300&amp;pubid=ra-MyID">
  <img src="http://s7.addthis.com/static/btn/v2/lg-share-en.gif" width="125" height="16" alt="Bookmark and Share" style="border:0"/>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var addthis_config = {
    "data_track_addressbar":false,
    "ui_show_promo":false
  };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-myID"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ever have one of those moments where you could have sworn you tried something and it didn't work, later to find that you must have done something stupid because it did work?

I'm having one of those moments.

I can execute the following function that will reinitialize the buttons:

```
addthis.button('.addthis_button');
```

The .addthis_button being the class that contains the button.